# Deterministic Finite Automata and Turing Machine

Tags: theory, computation-theory, turing-machines

I have the following question from a past paper that I'm studying which my peers and myself can't seem to answer, we believe that it's not Turning decidable but we're not sure how to formalise that and prove it.

> Let a Deterministic Finite Automata, *D*, accept all inputs *w* over
>   the alphabet {0, 1} if *w* contains an equal number of 0s and 1s.
>   **Formalise** the computational problem of deciding whether a given *D* accepts input *w* as a language and show whether or not the problem is **Turing decidable**.

Comment: I don't quite get it. You define a language _L_ as consisting of all words where the number of 0s is equal to the number of 1s? As far as I understand, this language is not regular, that is there is not DFA that accepts this language, so the problem makes no sense... Or do you consider DFAs whose language _includes_ _L_, that is which accept a superset of _L_?

Comment: Petr, I believe it's the latter

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the task correctly: a^m b^m is not context-free (see Pumping lemma), but here the question states that there is an equal amount of 0s and 1s ... i.e. 01011000001111. This is not the language 0^m 1^m IIRC. So maybe it is context free and therefore a autmata should exist?